# Adding gradually decreasing spaces in java with nested for loops in this java program, beginner question

Tags: java

currently trying to write this in java, but i cant seem to get the spaces and the colons correct with for loops.

```
|"""""""""|
 \:::::::/
  \:::::/
   \:::/
    \:/
    /:\
   /:::\
  /:::::\
 /:::::::\
|"""""""""|
```

^ the thing im trying to write

my code currently :

```
public class nested4loops {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        timething();
    }
    public static void timething() {
        System.out.println("|\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"|");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int s = 0; s < i; s++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("\\");
            for (int b = 7; b > i; b--) {
                System.out.print(":");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Currently however, this code prints:

```
|"""""""""|
\:::::::
 \::::::
  \:::::
   \::::
    \:::
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, is to have 2 loops, one for the top part and one for the bottom part.

However, that means that the body of those loops are repeated, which violates the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (Don't Repeat Yourself).

That can of course be handled by moving the common logic to methods, e.g. like this:

```java
public static void printHourGlass(int size) {
    printEndRow(size);
    for (int row = 1; row < size; row++)
        printGlassRow(row, size, '\\', '/');
    for (int row = size - 1; row > 0; row--)
        printGlassRow(row, size, '/', '\\');
    printEndRow(size);
}

private static void printEndRow(int size) {
    System.out.println("|" + repeat('"', size * 2 - 1) + "|");
}

private static void printGlassRow(int row, int size, char left, char right) {
    System.out.println(repeat(' ', row) + left + repeat(':', (size - row) * 2 - 1) + right);
}

private static String repeat(char ch, int count) {
    char[] buf = new char[count];
    Arrays.fill(buf, ch);
    return new String(buf);
}
```

*Tests*

```java
printHourGlass(3);
printHourGlass(5);
printHourGlass(9);
```

*Outputs*

```
|"""""|
 \:::/
  \:/
  /:\
 /:::\
|"""""|
```

```
|"""""""""|
 \:::::::/
  \:::::/
   \:::/
    \:/
    /:\
   /:::\
  /:::::\
 /:::::::\
|"""""""""|
```

```
|"""""""""""""""""|
 \:::::::::::::::/
  \:::::::::::::/
   \:::::::::::/
    \:::::::::/
     \:::::::/
      \:::::/
       \:::/
        \:/
        /:\
       /:::\
      /:::::\
     /:::::::\
    /:::::::::\
   /:::::::::::\
  /:::::::::::::\
 /:::::::::::::::\
|"""""""""""""""""|
```